# Meaninig for 'to cover a question'?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I saw a [video](https://youtu.be/sz1qaKt0KGQ?t=7) with such phrase:

> another day another really boring question to cover...

So, what does that means? Is it something like 'answer the question'? Or something more specific?

Comment: Yes it is. The implication is **in full**, possibly with a discussion, analysis or similar.

Comment: [Correction: What does that mean?]

Comment: There should be a comma in there, like "another ***day,*** another really..."

Comment: are you asking about the "another day, another ...question" or about what "covering a question" means?

Comment: @gotube the second, you can see it in title of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Definition 9 in [Merriam Webster’s dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cover):

> : to have sufficient scope to include or take into account

Also the definition given at the end for the related “cover ground”:

> : to deal with a subject or assignment in a particular manner

Answer (score 1):

There's a well known English expression: "Another day, another dollar", which refers to being that little bit richer after completing another day's work.

Based on knowledge of that expression, you can replace "dollar" with anything that comes up regularly in your life. A parent might say, "Another day, another load of laundry." A supporter of a losing team might say, "Another day, another loss".

This person often posts videos talking about difficult questions in programming on YouTube, so for him, it's "Another day, another really boring question to cover."

Comment: Main issues was with cover+answer, never saw such verb with this noun. But 'another dollar' was also very courious, than you.